# WooCommerce Layered Nav Product Filter Widget - multiple attributes don't work as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filter, attributes

I have a problem with WooCommerce and filtering by multiple attributes at a time using the Layered Nav widgets. I know there are a couple of other plugins offering ajax filtering, but the documentation for them doesn't seem to suggest they will work out this problem, and the WC docs offer nothing on this issue. I can't tell if I'm missing something obvious here because I imagine EVERY site that uses filters wants them to work in the way I outline below, not as they work currently.

My site uses three attributes:
- Colour
- Clothing type
- Brand

I have setup 3 instances of the Layered Nav widget in the sidebar to allow customers to find what they want. For all 3 I am using the query type of "OR" so that if a customer enables the Blue and Green and Red filter options, they can see any product that is either Blue OR Green OR Red. Similarly for Brand and clothing type.

Where I get stuck is that these widgets don't seem to have an option to specify AND or OR between attributes. I would expect the following logic when I use a clothing filter on a website:

Color: green OR blue
AND
Brand: Nike OR Adidas
AND
Type: Accessories OR Tops OR Bottoms

but instead everything is just one long OR query so a piece of clothing could be blue OR an accessory OR nike OR green OR adidas.

The result is that customers get lots of products they don't want to see i.e. a Puma product shows up because it's Blue, even if the brand filter only wants Nike or Adidas.

Is there any way to chain queries together so that WITHIN an attribute we use OR, but across attributes we use AND? I imagine the SQL query for this wouldn't be too complex, I'm just hoping there's an extension that would handle this for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

/woocommerce/includes/cass-wc-query.php 729 line.
Change function layered_nav_query like this:

```
/**
 * Layered Nav post filter.
 *
 * @param array $filtered_posts
 * @return array
 */
public function layered_nav_query( $filtered_posts ) {
    global $_chosen_attributes;

    if ( sizeof( $_chosen_attributes ) > 0 ) {

        foreach ( $_chosen_attributes as $attribute => $data ) {
            $matched_products_from_attribute = array();
            $filtered = false;

            if ( sizeof( $data['terms'] ) > 0 ) {
                foreach ( $data['terms'] as $value ) {

                    $args = array(
                        'post_type'     => 'product',
                        'numberposts'   => -1,
                        'post_status'   => 'publish',
                        'fields'        => 'ids',
                        'no_found_rows' => true,
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy'  => $attribute,
                                'terms'     => $value,
                                'field'     => 'term_id'
                            )
                        )
                    );

                    $post_ids = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_layered_nav_query_post_ids', get_posts( $args ), $args, $attribute, $value );

                    if ( ! is_wp_error( $post_ids ) ) {

                        if ( sizeof( $matched_products_from_attribute ) > 0 || $filtered ) {
                            $matched_products_from_attribute = $data['query_type'] == 'or' ? array_merge( $post_ids, $matched_products_from_attribute ) : array_intersect( $post_ids, $matched_products_from_attribute );
                        } else {
                            $matched_products_from_attribute = $post_ids;
                        }

                        $filtered = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            $results = isset($results)
                ? array_intersect($results, $matched_products_from_attribute)
                : $matched_products_from_attribute;

            $this->filtered_product_ids_for_taxonomy[ $attribute ] = $matched_products_from_attribute;
        }

        if ( $filtered ) {

            WC()->query->layered_nav_post__in   = $results;
            WC()->query->layered_nav_post__in[] = 0;

            if ( sizeof( $filtered_posts ) == 0 ) {
                $filtered_posts   = $results;
                $filtered_posts[] = 0;
            } else {
                $filtered_posts   = array_intersect( $filtered_posts, $results );
                $filtered_posts[] = 0;
            }

        }
    }
    return (array) $filtered_posts;
}
```

Comment: What? Why? A bit more explanation would be really appreciated, expecially since the line looks not right and that function is deprecated since 2.6.0..